# Date not showing in rails app when requesting year field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a data type called:

```
t.date :finishdate
```

And I have a select field:

```
<%= f.select :finishdate, (Time.zone.now.year - 10)..(Time.zone.now.year) + 5,{}, class: "form-control" %>
```

But i can't seem to display the year? at the moment I'm using:

```
<%= w.finishdate %>
```

But nothing displays, I have also tried:

```
<%= w.finishdate.year %>
```

But then get a error

```
undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `finishdate` appears to return `nil`. Are you sure it is actually set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the text-field i got it to work using this:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Completed in:</label>
      <%= f.date_select :finishdate , { discard_day: true, discard_month: true }, { :class => 'form-control' } %><br/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= w.finishdate.strftime('%Y') if  w.finishdate.present? %>
```

Comment: some explanation would make this bit of code clearer

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This will always set nil to `finishdate`. Because, this will always retrun

```
2.0.0-p0 :006 > (Time.zone.now.year - 10)..(Time.zone.now.year + 5)
 => 2006..2021
```

If you try to save 2006 or other year in `finishdate` field. you will get `nil` because your field type is `date` not `string`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= w.finishdate.strftime('%Y') %>
```

Comment: If `w.finishdate` return `nil` this will produce error too.